# Getting syntax error, unexpected token with jQuery .ajax() method from YQL JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, yql

i'm trying to include a [JSON file generated by YQL](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=57aa32bf3481c8dca0c07afcf9b9dc29&_render=json) via jQuery following [this tutorial](http://www.jquery4u.com/json/ajaxjquery-getjson-simple/) and get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
```

This is the code I currently try to use:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: "http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=57aa32bf3481c8dca0c07afcf9b9dc29&_render=json",
 async: false,
 beforeSend: function(x) {
  if(x &amp;&amp; x.overrideMimeType) {
   x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
  }
 },
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data){
  alert("success");
 }
});
```

I'm not as comfortable with JSON/JQuery/JS as I would like, but it's not really my primary field of expertise ;) . I'd really appreciate any help given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this your problem?

```
x &amp;&amp; x.overrideMimeType
```

instead of

```
x && x.overrideMimeType
```

Comment: Well, that's quick, correct and totally embarassing. Thanks a lot!

Comment: sometimes it just takes another set of eyes

Comment: Hey again, I'm sure this is just my missing knowledge of JS objects, could you point me to a source explaining why the following won't work on the data object?

`$('body').append(data.query.results.a.content);`

Comment: What does your response json look like?

Comment: that's where I would start.  see if you can use something like [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see the response and make sure the `json` is laid out like you expect

Comment: parse your json like  data.value.items[0].a.content